# file validation, prevent file change in C++

Tags: c++, file, validation, hash, md5

**Which is the easiest way to validate a file and to prevend changing it's content?**

*It is like to get `md5 hash` of file and compare saved md5 hash with current `md5 hash`.*

**How to do it in C++?**

*Example :*

I have a file : 
**myfile.txt**

```
I am content
```

basically what I want :

```
bool validate()
{
  string saved_content = "I am content";
  if(saved_content !== CONTENT_FROM_FILE("myfile.txt")) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: There's no way to prevent someone from changing the file unless you get the OS to enforce this (e.g. acquire an exclusive lock, or use appropriate filesystem permissions).

Comment: Create an SHA1 sum, ask the user to write it down or print it. Next time when you read the file, ask the user to input the previously written down checksum. That is pretty much the only real way of preventing a user that has access to the file from tampering with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using a useful library OpenSSL. It has [some function](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html) to calculate the hash (md5,sha1,...) 
You should store hash value in memory or in secured file and periodically recalculate the hash of file. Cryptographic hash functions are more reliably than CRC32

Answer (score 0):

You can use CRC also to verify if any change has occurred. [Here](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403658?pgno=1) are a couple of ways of using CRC in C++

EDIT - Its not very clear from the question, but I am assuming that you want to detect changes in a file over a period of time. So my approach is take a CRC and store it someplace, subsequently you can compare the latest CRC with the stored value to know if the file has been modified or not.